# Error getting ble device services using FromBluetoothAddressAsync

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

**edit**

it's A known problem with some microsoft security issue
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58da3fdb-a0e1-4161-8af3-778b6839f4e1/bluetooth-bluetoothledevicefromidasync-does-not-complete-on-10015063?forum=wdk

**adding registery CoInitializeSecurity values as mentioned fixed the problem!**

i'm trying to read A BLE device services using An Advertisment watcher.
i've implemnted the service read inside the listenter, the Code:

```
   private async void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
    {

        if (!gotSignal)
        {
            gotSignal = true;
            device = await Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(args.BluetoothAddress);
            service = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(device.DeviceId);

        }
          ...
     }
```

the problem is that I can't get the BluetoothLEDevice object, when I reach this line, it is not getting back any value and it skips the next lines inside the listener.
NOTE: I've installed windows creators update and before the installation, the function BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync has worked.

Comment: I asked a similar question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43568096/3187714 Are you running as desktop/exe program or a UWP application? For me, this code works as a UWP app but not as a desktop exe.

Comment: I am running A desktop program too.

Comment: I guess you need to pair the device first

Comment: I know, I'm intersted on getting the device services without pairing.

Comment: The new Creators no pairing code also works fine in a UWP app. I too am interested in not having to pair with a windows desktop program. I updated my similar question because after a bit more research, I found my problem is the same as yours -- FromBluetoothAddressAsync never seems to return.

Comment: I did find if I added the optional second argument BluetoothAddressType.Public to FromBluetoothAddressAsync, the function returns, but unfortunately the return device is null... BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(args.BluetoothAddress, BluetoothAddressType.Public);

Comment: Thanks i'll try do something with the second argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

it's A known problem with some microsoft security issue https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58da3fdb-a0e1-4161-8af3-778b6839f4e1/bluetooth-bluetoothledevicefromidasync-does-not-complete-on-10015063?forum=wdk

adding registery CoInitializeSecurity values as mentioned fixed the problem!