# Connect BLE device from F#

Tags: .net, f#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

Since F# is not (yet) supported by .net native compiler, is there another process to connect a BLE device from an F# application?

As far as I can see, 32feet uses UWP, and all other examples I found are also based on UWP. And as far as I know, UWP is based on the .net native copmpiler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to use Bluetooth LE from a c# desktop app in windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333179/is-there-any-way-to-use-bluetooth-le-from-a-c-sharp-desktop-app-in-windows-10)